# How can I generate variables with 100 indices?

Tags: python, variables, gurobi

I'm very beginner at python and gurobipy library,
and I want to generate bunch of individual variables with indices, like x1, x2, ... ,x100...
Is there any faster and easier way to generate them? 
I tried "for" structure in various form but shell keeps returning syntax error message... :(
HELP PLEASE!

Comment: Use a sequence or a mapping instead of creating multiple variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say that I like doing it this way - but whenever you have to do such tedious work manually...

```
for i in range(1,101):
    globals()["x{}".format(i)] = "test"

print x53 # prints test
```

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is *very* lame!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a group of values that can be indexed, use a list (indexes are 0 start):

```
mylist = ["some item", 23, "other item", 99]
twentythree = mylist[1]
```

You can add items to the list with `.append(<item>)`:

```
mylist.append("new item")
```

You can make a list of 100 items with `range(100)`, but the resulting list will contain values 0 to 99.